# Why openTelemetry needs to be setup before any other code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-telemetry

OpenTelemetry SDK for Node.js requires tracing to be set up before running (or even importing) any other code. An example of such recommendation can be seen in the [official documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/nodejs/#setup).

I tried to ignore that advice and I could see that no traces are being logged. Why is that? I had a look into the SDK code and I do not see any reason why the SDK behaves this way.

What am I missing? I'd like to understand what is the root cause of the requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because it intercepts the module resolution and wraps implementations. Node will cache modules and it would be nearly impossible to monkey patch after the fact. You can see this in the instrumentation packages.

Comment: I think it would still be (more or less) easily possible to monkey-patch the module objects afterwards, but the hard thing is to choose which modules to patch (out of the many for which instrumentation exists). Intercepting the module loading solves that - only the libraries that are actually used by the application are getting patched.

Comment: Great explanation. Ugly design.